# Identity permutation as a product of non-zero transpositions

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles

We know that an identity permutation can be expressed as a product of zero transpositions. However, in some books, it is expressed as a product of non-zero transpositions. For example in the following permutation $f$.

$f=\begin{pmatrix}
1 ~2 ~3~ 4~ 5 ~6\\
1~ 6~5~3~4~2
\end{pmatrix}=(1)(26)(354)=(12)(21)(26)(34)(35)$.

I do not understand why $(1)$ is expressed as $(12)(21)$? Specifically, why $2$ has been chosen here?

Will the following results also be true?

(a) $f=(13)(31)(26)(34)(35)$

(b) $f=(14)(41)(26)(34)(35)$

(c) $f=(15)(51)(26)(34)(35)$

(d) $f=(16)(61)(26)(34)(35)$, etc.?

Comment: All those expressions for the given permutation are correct. There might be a reason why you wanted to use $(12)(21)$ instead of $(1)(2)$ or $(1)$ or nothing at all, but the reason would depend on the context. If you have actually seen this in print please [edit] the question to provide the context.

Comment: @EthanBolker thanks for the comment. It's clear now

Comment: You're welcome. Please delete the question or answer it yourself and accept the answer to that the question does not remain on the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comment that all the expressions are correct. However, the use of a particular expression depends on the context of interest.

For instance a permutation $f=(1)$ is the same as

$f=\begin{pmatrix}
1 ~2 ~3~ 4~ 5 ~6\\
1~ 2~3~4~5~6
\end{pmatrix}$.

Moreover, an identity permutation can be expressed as product of either zero transpositions or the product of a transposition with its inverse transposition.

These suffice that

(a) $f=(13)(31)(26)(34)(35)$

(b) $f=(14)(41)(26)(34)(35)$

(c) $f=(15)(51)(26)(34)(35)$

(d) $f=(16)(61)(26)(34)(35)$, etc. are all true.